# What's the difference between using `if condition then` and just `condition && {}`

Tags: bash

I was just wondering if there's any practical difference between writing the following bash:

```
if [ <some condition> ]; then
  <some statement>
fi
```

and the following:

```
[ <some condition> ] && {
  <some statement>
}
```

Is there any difference in how this is executed, or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much logical nor linguistic difference at this point. But if you were to grow this into something bigger, then the verbose syntax with `if` gives more space for adding `elif`s and `else`. If you stick to the logical operators, then it will be much harder to read. Try it yourself.

For example, rewrite the following using `&&` and/or `||`.

```
if [ 1 -eq 2 ]; then echo ok; elif [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo lif; else echo el; fi
```

Comment: Also flow of logic: consider `if A; then B; else C; fi` versus `A && B || C`. Will C be executed when A succeeds but B fails?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they are equivalent. In both cases the statement is executed only if the condition is true.

It is a difference in style, I prefer the first option.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks. I though I remembered differently, but it seems that was `false || false`, not `false && false`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all shells support:

```
[ <some condition> ] && {
  <some statement>
}
```

Some shells are supporting it by a executable in /usr/bin/[.

To test if your shell are using /usr/bin/[ just do:

```
$ builtin [
sh: 1: builtin: not found
```

This means the shell is using /usr/bin/[, but if you get something else your shell support it...

But bash has the support.

Comment: Umm... Whether the shell uses its built-in `[` or the external `[` should not really matter.

Comment: Well better if i say not all environment have external [ ?

Comment: Aren't both `if/then` and `&&` part of the POSIX shell syntax? Sure, there are non-POSIX shells that might not support one, but then they might also not support the other, so...

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini if a shell doesn't have a `[` built-in, it will use the external `/bin/[` for both `if [...]; then` and `[..] &&`. `[` is not part of the syntax, `if grep ...; then ...` works just file. Also, your shell is telling you that it cannot find a built-in, function or external command named `builtin`, not that `[` is not a built-in ;-)